# What equations do I need to find the requested parameters?

Tags: filters, control-systems

> Consider a filter of the form $$ _{posic}() = \alpha_1+\alpha_2e^{-sh}.$$
> Find the parameters $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb R$, and $h > 0$ such that
>
> 1. $P_{\theta\phi}F_{posic}$ is an FIR (finite impulse response)  system
> 2. the static gain $F_{posic} = 1$,
> 3. $h$ is a smallest possible delay guaranteeing all that
>    in symbolic form in terms of the parameters of the system,
>
> given $ P_{\theta\phi} = -\frac{mlrs^2}{(J_b+ml^2)s^2 + \zeta s + mlg}$,
> where $ m,l,r,J_b$   are known constants.

I've tried computing the poles and then using $Res(G(s),s_i) = 0$ to satisfy 1. (since my poles are simple and this should guarantee FIR)  and a third equation from 2. but the system of equations I get doesn't have a nontrivial solution.

How do I approach finding a solution?

Comment: Hey. Please don't cross post, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666666/what-equations-do-i-need-to-find-the-requested-parameters , without telling either side you did - that potentially just duplicates effort!